# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Tags: php, foreach

i keep getting the error for this code even though it works as it should when i run it in browser, but when called by `include_once` it doesnt work due to the error

```
    foreach(($hostlist->uploaded) as $uploaded) {
    if (strcmp($uploaded->url,"http://someurl.com/")==0) {
    $host = simplexml_load_file($config['hostlist']);
    unset($host->uploaded->url);
    unset($host->uploaded->pass);
    $host->uploaded->addChild('url',"http://anotherurl.com/");
    $host->uploaded->addChild('pass',"anotherpass");
    $host->uploaded->asXML($config['hostlist']);
    $host->asXML($config['hostlist']);`
    echo "URL Changed to  http://anotherurl.com/";
    }
  }
```

knowing that the variables are as follows:

```
$config['hostlist'] = 'xml/host.xml';

$hostlist = simplexml_load_file($config['hostlist']);
```

and this is a sample of the xml file:

```
<host> 
 <uploaded>
  <work>yes</work>
  <url>http://someurl.com/</url>
  <pass>pass</pass>
 </uploaded>
</host>
```

Comment: `<host>
<uploaded>
<work>yes</work><url>http://someurl.com/</url><pass>pass</pass></uploaded>
</host>`

Comment: i enclosed it as a test after many failures :)

Comment: Do `var_dump` on `$hostlist` and you may see that it is boolean false which means that php didn't location the file. Check file_exists(`$config['hostlist']`) first and see if that is true. Yo might need to adjust include path or use absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had early mentioned via comments, your issue maybe that the file is using a relative path and being accessed via `include_once` by a script on a different folder, which causes the file path of your XML to be invalid.

Here is a simple example of what may be happening to you.

I have the following folder structure:

```
root
  - include_folder/
  - include_folder/read_host.php
  - include_folder/xml
  - include_folder/xml/host.xml
  - test_xml.php
```

When accessing `include_folder/read_host.php` it reads the file just fine.

This is my `read_host.php`:

```
<?php

$config['hostlist'] = 'xml/host.xml';
$hostlist = simplexml_load_file($config['hostlist']);
foreach($hostlist->uploaded as $uploaded)
{
    echo $uploaded->work, "\n";
    echo $uploaded->url, "\n";
    echo $uploaded->pass, "\n";
}
```

The output:

```
yes
http://someurl.com/
pass
```

However if I access from `test_xml.php` which have the following content:

```
<?php
include_once('include_folder/read_host.php');
echo "what happens";
```

It fails with error:

> PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "xml/host.xml" in /home/admin/include_folder/read_host.php on line 4
>   PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/admin/include_folder/read_host.php on line 5
>   PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/admin/include_folder/read_host.php on line 5
>
> what happens

However if I change `$config['hostlist'] = 'xml/host.xml';` to the absolute path to the XML file it works just fine and output:

```
yes
http://someurl.com/
pass
what happens
```

So in my case the absolute folder was:

```
$config['hostlist'] = '/home/admin/include_folder/xml/host.xml';
```

Comment: thanks a lot,
i've done this with another file just earlier today but i just lost the idea when editing this file.
thanks again